# Youtube API: Get the channel or username from the videoID

Tags: youtube-api

I've hunted around, and I'm not seeing how it's possible to fetch any user info by using only a videoID (from a video that a user uploaded), preferably without oAuth. I just need either the user's channel or user name.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list responds only with video info and requires oAuth.

So, for example. Given the "v" id in this following url, I could fetch the channel id, UCAIIYxc9Q5uHOUeoF3EWzkA, without requiring the user's permission. (this is all public anyway):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH2zbHrRY9A

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

The call would be https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=FH2zbHrRY9A&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

channelID will be in the snippet returned.

Comment: Awesome, John. I was looking for channelId as a property, not "snippet" which, as you mentioned, contains channelid. I should have read more carefully. Thanks!

Comment: For all testing the link above, the video was deleted and does not return the channel id. Try another video link, for instance: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=oDOXeO9fAg4&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`